# Attaching categories from one table to entries in another MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I have a database which takes user submitted data, the entries from which I want to group under one or several of about 10 categories.

So for example, you add your entry to my site, say its all about your business (a car valeting service), and I offer you the opportunity to categorize your entry in any number of 10 fixed categories (automotive, mobile service, etc), so if a user searches for businesses under the 'automotive' or 'mobile service' category, your business is returned from the query.

So as I have taken from most of the answers on here, to achieve this I have my database with three tables (structure below), one for your business entry, one listing the set categories, and one relational table to which I've added the unique key from the prior two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `business` (
`bus_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`bus_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
`bus_dscpn` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`bus_url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`bus_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`category_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `tbl_works_categories` (
`bus_id` INT NOT NULL, 
`category_id` INT NOT NULL
)
```

What I cannot figure out for the life of me is, when you select which categories you'd like your business associated with from my form which is processed with PHP, how to actually associate them in the database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your form returns the category IDs for each category selected and that those IDs correspond with category_id in your categories table.

First you insert your business record into your business table, this will give you the auto increment number (mysql_insert_id function in PHP or whatever function for the library you are using). So, you have an `$idfromfunction` somewhere stored.

With that business ID, then loop through your category IDs

(perhaps already having used):

```
SELECT category_id, category_name
FROM categories
```

(... and showed this list to your user through checkboxes or drop list or whatever)

After the user chooses one `$categoryidfromform`, you can then insert into your tbl_works_categories table

```
INSERT INTO tbl_works_categories
    (bus_id, category_id)
VALUES
    ( $idfromfunction, $categoryidfromform) ;
```

Comment: My form for catagories doesn't do anything yet @mikeq - that's what i had no idea on where to start, but i think i can just about make sense of your answer. In the form structure, i have the catagories as checkboxes to store in an array - is that the best way of letting the user select them? Thanks

Comment: thats what I guessed when you said "when you select which catagories you'd like your business associated with from my form which is processed with PHP", so my answer is based on that you already had the category IDs returned and in PHP you just didnt know how to add them to the database table, is that the case?

Comment: @mikeq hi, no, i don't have the id's returned yet, with regards the catagories, apart from setting up the databases i haven't done anything apart from the form using checkboxes for input and "catagory[]" for the checkbox name. The business data (input, add and retrieval is fine and working), but this has me stumped - completely!

Comment: @ypercube - Jeez, is it really that simple?! I think i'm going to go and sit in a dark corner! Once i figure out how to return the id's from the checkboxes, that looks like it'll work, then i'll mark this question answered. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dan: Yes. it's that simple. One `INSERT INTO tbl_works_categories` for every category you want to add to a business. It could also be more complicated with one `INSERT` inserting many rows (categories) but try to make the simple way working first.

Comment: @ypercube Hi, right, that worked a treat, thank you very much. Can you now help me with my query to return the relevant business based on the tag_id's associated to the bus-id? I'm having some trouble getting my head around the logic, never mind the code? Thanks

Comment: @Dan: Better post a new question (if I understand correctly that it's not relevant to this one)

Comment: @ypercube that's just what i was thinking but I don't want to overstay my welcome and other people's helpfulness! Will be up in couple of minutes, Thanks ypercube

Answer (score 1):

To get a business data with all categories you can do,

```
SELECT bus.*, cat.category_name FROM business bus 
    JOIN tbl_works_categories twc USING (bus_id) 
    JOIN categories cat USING (category_id) 
    WHERE bus.bus_id = ?
```

To retrieve business data from category name, just switch the WHERE param

```
SELECT bus.*, cat.category_name FROM business bus 
    JOIN tbl_works_categories twc USING (bus_id) 
    JOIN categories cat USING (category_id) 
    WHERE cat.category_name = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that it's simple. Perhaps this will answer your questions.

I assume that your form has check-boxes or a multi-select box to allow the user to select categories for his/her business. And that the "value" attribute of the check-box/select-box is set to the category ID, as stored in the `categories` table. So, now when the form is submitted, you'll get in the PHP script, along with other inputs from the form, an array with the IDs of the categories selected by the user. Let's call it $_POST['categories']

**METHOD 1**:

a. Run the query - INSERT INTO `business` ...

b. read the ID of the last entry made into `business` table using either `mysql_insert_id` or `mysqli->insert_id`, depending on either you are using MySQL or MySQLi library. Suppose you store this ID in `$busId`

c. From $_POST['categories'], generate a comma-separated string using `implode()`. Suppose you store this string in `$strCategories`

d.

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_works_categories` (`bus_id`, `category_id`)
SELECT $busId, `category_id`
FROM `categories`
WHERE `category_id` IN ($strCategories);
```

**METHOD 2**:

Alternatively, you may as well loop through the POST array and generate INSERT query, like:

```
$q = '';
if (!empty($_POST['categories'])) {
    $q = 'INSERT INTO `tbl_works_categories` (`bus_id`, `category_id`) VALUES ';
    foreach ($_POST['categories'] as $categoryId) {
        $q .= '(' . $busId . ', ' . $categoryId . '),';
    }
}
$q = trim($q, ','); // to remove the trailing comma
if (!empty($q)) {
    // execute query $q
}
```

Hope the above helps. I haven't tested any of the above codes, so you might need to do some debugging if anything is broken. Please feel free to ask if you've any questions.