# Storing Checkbox Array Data in individual variables

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Another simple one from me:

I have a form which features a checkbox section called:

```
name = "cat[]"
```

from which i am collecting answers with

```
$cat = $_POST ['cat'];
```

Now I can find out what or how many options were submitted and echo their values with

```
foreach ($cat as $item) echo "$item";
```

But what i want to do is store each returned value in an individual variable so i can add them individually to my table in MySql.

can anyone help me do this? Or am i going about things in a backwards way (probably)?

As always, any of your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there something *wrong* with manually listing out `$_POST['cat']['itemX']` in your SQL?

Comment: @Jason McCreary Hi Jason, probably not but as i'm just finding my way with this, i'm afraid my questions can come across as, well, stupid. Unfortunaltley i don't know what i don't know.

Comment: I don't mean to imply the question is stupid. But it's more about what you're trying to do. Unless you are dynamically generating your SQL, it's pretty common to just manually list your fields in your SQL statement.

Comment: Believe me Jason, all my questions seem stupid when the the answer finally dawns on me - I'm turning out to be very grateful to the StackOverflow community. I think Neal has pushed me in the right direction, but this should explain why i was trying to get individual values out of the array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428612/attaching-catagories-from-one-table-to-entries-in-another-mysql thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($cat as $item) {

    $query = "INSERT into `table_name` (`col_name`) VALUES ('$item');";
    //do something with $query

}
```

Comment: thanks, that's great but its not quite what I'm after unfortunaltey as i need to loop through each value returned and insert into a table with a relevant id from another submitted form item, so really, i just want to assign each one to a variable that i can then use. Thanks

Comment: you already have all of them in an array. im a bit confused as to what you want

Comment: Sorry Neal. Yes i understand that if they're submitted, they're stored in that array. If you have the time to look at ypercube's answer to me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428612/attaching-catagories-from-one-table-to-entries-in-another-mysql, that should explain why i *think* i need to do this.

Comment: oh hang on, i think i can do it as youy've suggested and just amend the query to include my other id! You're a gent, thanks!

Comment: @Dan ur welcome, please remember to select an `accepted anser` on this and the other questions you have asked in the past